# Compound interest calculator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```
def bank(balance, extra, time, intrestRate):
    intrest = (balance + extra * time * intrestRate )/100
    return intrest

balance = float(input("Enter current balance:"))
extra = float(input("Amount added at end of year:"))
time = int(input("How many years:"))
intrestRate = float(input("Amount of intrest:"))

intrest = bank(balance, extra, time, intrestRate)

for i in range(time): 
    amount = extra + balance * (1.0 + intrestRate) ** i
    print("Amount:", amount)
```

So this is what I have, and I think the issue is whenever adding the extra amount at the end of each year something is wrong with how I a doing the math.. ( Not my strong suite )

Using https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php

To check my calculations and it seems like the first year comes out correct but... everything else after that is wrong.

Comment: Well, typically interest is paid/earned by the month, not by the year.  And what is the "extra" for?

Comment: @TimRoberts It was just asked for by the assignment. If the person added an extra amount into their account at the end of each year.

Comment: OK,  but don't think about computing year 19 directly.  Instead, adjust the balance year by year.  Just `balance = balance * (1.0 + interestRate) + extra` every year.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you, that got it working correctly.

Comment: Hi @Blue , Have you seen my answer yet? please give some feed back, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use `for i in range(time):`? Can't you just do `amount = extra + balance * (1.0 + intrestRate) ^ time`? Also, you are only adding "extra" once, you should add it for every year.

Answer (score 0):

##### Compound Interest Formula:

[image]

> **A** represents the final amount in the account
> **P** is the principal (the original amount of money)
> **t** represents the time in years
> **n** represents the number of times per year, interest is compounded
> **r** represents the rate of interest

##### Code:

```py
n = int(input("Number of times per year, interest is compounded"))
.
.
.
amount = balance * (1.0 + intrestRate/n) ** (i*n)
```

##### Example:

If you have a bank account whose *principal* = $1,000, and your bank *compounds* the *interest* twice a year at an *interest rate* of 5%, how much money do you have in your account at the year's end?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem. This should work for you. I have also included plotting since you mentioned that it was for an assignment. You can remove it if you don't need it.

`Note: install matplotlib if not done already: (pip install matplotlib)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


principal = float(input("Enter current balance:"))
extra = float(input("Amount added at end of year:"))
years = int(input("How many years:"))
rate = float(input("Amount of intrest:"))/100


# initially, the amount is the principal
# extra is only added at the end of the year
amount = principal

# interest earned is also 0 initially 
interest = 0

# needed for plotting
# Comment these out if you don't want to plot
y = [principal]
x = [i for i in range(years+1)]



print(f"year: 0\tamount:{amount}")

for year in range(1, years+1):
    interest = amount * rate # calculate the interest on the current amount
    amount = amount + interest + extra # add the extra and interest
    y.append(amount) # comment this out if plotting not needed
    print(f"year: {year}\tInterest: {round(interest,2)}\tAmount: {round(amount,2)}\n")
    
    
print(f"Total Interest Earned: {interest}, Amount: {amount}")


plt.plot(x,y, marker="o")
plt.xlabel("Amount")
plt.ylabel("Years")
plt.show()
```